# issues with isspace and replace()

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to write a program that will read a 2-character user inputed string, "passCode" and replace any space " " with "__". I can only edit the space between the passCode initialization and the cout. Currently, when the user inputs "1 ", it should print out "1_", but it just prints out "1 " again. The two if statements are supposed to look at each character separately in the string and if it is a space, it is supposed to replace that space with an underscore. However, it does not seem to be working. I cannot tell if it is becuase I need an else statement, but I dont know what it would need to be. If there arent any spaces in the string, then nothing is to be done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string passCode;

   passCode = "1 ";

   if (isspace(passCode.at(0)) == true){
      passCode.replace(0, 1, "_");
   }
   if (isspace(passCode.at(1)) == true){
      passCode.replace(1, 1, "_");
   }

   cout << passCode << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `replace` not working or is it not being called?

Comment: If you step through the code line by line in a debugger, does it do what you expect it to?

Comment: not sure how i would know if its not working. I'm using it in the only way I know how to. I also just tried to put single quotes around the isspace parameters inside the parentheses like (isspace('passCode.at(0)') but it does not compile.

Comment: @RachelSugg you could test that by putting print statements inside the if blocks and check for any output

Comment: Consider using [`std::replace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) instead of manual replacements, eg: `std::replace(passCode.begin(), passCode.end(), ' ', '_');` Or use `std::relace_if()` instead, eg: `std::replace_if(passCode.begin(), passCode.end(), [](char c) { return (std::isspace(c) != 0); }, '_');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `isspace` does not return `bool`, it returns an `int`:

> **Return Value**
>
> A value different from zero (i.e., true) if indeed c is a white-space character. Zero (i.e., false) otherwise.

If you remove `== true` part, your code will work as expected:

```
if (isspace(passCode.at(0))){
    passCode.replace(0, 1, "_");
}
if (isspace(passCode.at(1))){
    passCode.replace(1, 1, "_");
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/bMzYFv)

Comment: thats strange. my textbook has isspace examples as returning either true or false.

Comment: @RachelSugg Version of the library deployed on ideone returns `1<<13`, i.e. `8192` ([demo](https://ideone.com/R7YVII)).

Comment: yes this worked, but im not sure I understand how. if its an if statement, what is it saying about the "if"?  looks to me like its just a single statement whereas an if statement compares two statements together.

Comment: @RachelSugg All control structures in C++ that need a logical expression, e.g.`if`, `while`, and `for`, rely on implicit comparison to zero. In other words, if you have `if (intvalue)` it is the same as `if (intvalue != 0)`. Same applies to values of other types, such as pointers.

Comment: FYI - std::isspace() from <locale> returns a bool.  std::isspace from <cctype> returns an int.